# Retrieve Year from string date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have the following column of dates:

`EXPIRY_DAT
31-Oct-17
31-Oct-17
18-Nov-18 12:11:10
31-Dec-12
31-Oct-17
31-Oct-17
18-Nov-18 12:11:10
31-Dec-12
31-Oct-17
31-Oct-17
20-Jul-18 19:20:33
31-Oct-18
31-Oct-18
11-Aug-19 21:52:56
31-Dec-12
.
.
.`

I would like to retrieve the year from these series in the form YYYY.
I already tried using the following line of SQL code:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EXPIRY_DAT, 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS'), 'YYYY'
```

although it returns me the error message:

**ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string**

Comment: Most of your strings have a date but don't have the time element, so the string format doesn't match the mask

Comment: Also, unless the code was pasted wrong, `TO_DATE()` and `TO_CHAR()` are in the wrong order. First convert to date (inner), then convert to char (outer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your dates are in one of the formats you showed, this could be enough:

```
-- test case
with dateTable(EXPIRY_DAT) as (
    select '31-Oct-17'            from dual union all
    select '31-Oct-17'            from dual union all
    select '18-Nov-18 12:11:10'   from dual union all
    select '31-Dec-12'            from dual union all
    select '31-Oct-17'            from dual union all
    select '31-Oct-17'            from dual union all
    select '18-Nov-18 12:11:10'   from dual union all
    select '31-Dec-12'            from dual union all
    select '31-Oct-17'            from dual union all
    select '31-Oct-17'            from dual union all
    select '20-Jul-18 19:20:33'   from dual union all
    select '31-Oct-18'            from dual union all
    select '31-Oct-18'            from dual union all
    select '11-Aug-19 21:52:56'   from dual union all
    select '31-Dec-12'            from dual
)
-- query
select to_char(to_date(substr(EXPIRY_DAT, 1, 9), 'dd-mon-yy'), 'yyyy')
from dateTable
```

Comment: just FYI some times the format is like the following example:

`03-SEP-15 18:37:31.540622` 

for which your answer is still valid

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
select extract(year from TO_DATE(SUBSTR(EXPIRY_DAT,1,9),'DD-Mon-YY')
from your_table
```

Comment: the transformation should lie between the `SELECT` and `FROM`

Comment: Modified... not big deal